# Authorized App not showing as IsAuthorized() when using FacebookWebContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am using the Facebook C# SDK.  This is based MOSTLY on the ASPNet-MVC3-JsSdk examples.  In my app, I have the standard Javascript code (taken directly from the sample app, for the most part).

```
function facebooklogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    alert(window.location.pathname);
                    // user authorized

                    window.location = window.location.origin + "/Account/FacebookLogon" + "?returnUrl=" + window.location.pathname;
                } else {
                    // user cancelled
                }
            }, { scope: "@ScoreTrack.Controllers.AccountController.ExtendedPermissions"});
        };
```

I basically want to redirect to my `Account.FacebookLogon()` controller action where I check for Authorization and if the user has authorized the app, then I set a FormsAuthentication cookie/token.

```
public ActionResult FacebookLogon(string returnURL)
{
    var fbWebContext = new FacebookWebContext(FacebookApplication.Current, ControllerContext.HttpContext); // or FacebookWebContext.Current;

    if (fbWebContext.IsAuthorized(@MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.ExtendedPermissions.Split(',')))
    {
        // If the User is Logged in and Authorized   
        var fbwc = new FacebookWebClient();
        dynamic me = fbwc.Get("me");
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
                        FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                        me.username, // user name
                        DateTime.Now,             //creation
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
                        false, //Persistent
                        me.username);

        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));                
    }
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/" + returnURL));
}
```

Everything works fantastically, up to a point:

I click on my Facebook login button...

- I am presented with authorization screen I click on "Login"
- I authorize the extended permissions (using new Extended Auth)
- Javascript redirects me to my `AccountController.FacebookLogon()` method
- `FacebookLogon()` method checks to see if Facebook is Authorized and C# SDK says it's not.

What up internet?  or FacebookC#SDK guys?  or other smart facebook C#  programmer dudes?

What the heck up?

Anyone?

Comment: If you use Windows Identity Foundation you can use claims-based identities, and the HttpContext.Current.User will be filled with facebook logon data.